# What do Americans call a tubelight?

Tags: american-english

A tubelight is a layman's term for a fluorescent tube lamp in South Asia. Will an American reader understand that this is what I am talking about if I state, "the store was lit by a single flickering tubelight"?

[image: tubelight image]

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluorescent+%2A%2Ctubelight&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfluorescent%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20lamps%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20lighting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20lamp%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20antibody%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20lights%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20dye%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20tubes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfluorescent%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctubelight%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Tubelight is new to me but understandable. We say fluorescent light, lamp, or bulb.

Answer (score 8):

AHD finds no instance neither of [tubelight](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tubelight) nor of [tube light](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tube%20light).

More generally, it is called a ***fluorescent light***. I first thought of neon lights but this [American](https://homesteady.com/about-us) site called [homesteady](https://homesteady.com/12338260/neon-vs-fluorescent-lighting) explains it well:

> ***Fluorescent lights*** are similar to neon devices. Like neon lights, *a very carefully controlled electrical current enters the light and arcs from one end of the bulb to the other, passing through a gas on its way*. However, ***the gas used in fluorescent lights has no neon***.

The *[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fluorescent)* defines ***fluorescent*** as

> Exhibiting or produced by fluorescence:
>
> - fluorescent corals; ***fluorescent light***.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fluorescent-light) gives the American definition of the ***object***:

> fluorescent light | AMERICAN DICTIONARY
>
> noun [ C ] US/ˌflʊˈres·ənt ˈlɑɪt, ˌflɔ-, ˌfloʊ-/
>
> ***a very bright, usually tube-shaped electric light used esp. in offices***

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tubelight%2Cneon+light%2Cfluorescent+light%2C+tube+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctubelight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneon%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfluorescent%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctube%20light%3B%2Cc0) finds that in American English, ***fluorescent light*** is prefered to tubelight or tube light, and even to neon light.

If you want to be really specific (fluorescent lights can be tubes or lights or lamps), the term ***fluorescent tube (light)*** is definitely used. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp) starts its article on Fluorescent Lamp by stating:

> "Tubelight" redirects here. For other uses, see Tubelight (disambiguation).

and then goes on

> A fluorescent lamp, or ***fluorescent tube***, is a low-pressure mercury-vapor gas-discharge lamp that uses fluorescence to produce visible light. An electric current in the gas excites mercury vapor, which produces short-wave ultraviolet light that then causes a phosphor coating on the inside of the lamp to glow.

Comment: They're starting to tail off in favour of more efficient LED lights, but CFLs *(**compact fluorescent lamps / lights**)* are in fact "tubes" - just not ***long, straight** tubes*. From my perspective, OP's lights are only a short step above Tilley lamps and gas mantles - they're definitely heading for "the dustbin of history".

Comment: This is what [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=compact+fluorescent+lamps&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01qbyTqLG3AC7sQ2YvCCGRTsuL-lA:1625656704672&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT_aGT69DxAhX4URUIHckgAhgQ_AUoAHoECAEQAg&biw=1372&bih=661&dpr=1.4) shows when you search "compact fluorescent lamps". Might not be necessarily a tube, it seems. Even Wikipedia does not limit it to a tube.

Comment: Indeed - and I see in the first page of results from your link that Ikea stopped selling CFLs last year.

Comment: I would say that 'the light from a flickering tube' is instantly understandable.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the usage *neon lights* in American English is pretty much interchangeable with *neon signs,* which are shaped into words or pictures and used to advertise. This is entirely distinct from our concept of *fluorescents,* the purpose of which is to provide light.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Yes, thank you for the detail. I only mentioned because I did not expect "fluorescent lights" to be so much more common than "neon lights", which is a very known expression.

Comment: @fev ["Neon sign"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluorescent+light%2Cfluorescent+lights%2Cneon+signs%2Cneon+lights%2C+neon+sign%2C+neon+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfluorescent%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfluorescent%20lights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneon%20signs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneon%20lights%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneon%20sign%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneon%20light%3B%2Cc0) shows more results in Ngram than anything.